# Struct with flexible member type?

Tags: c, struct, sdl

I'm working on a small game and i have a struct, containing sprite information. One of the members of that sprite can be either a SDL_Texture or, well, any other type. I'm writing this struct as a method of supporting multiple platforms. My entire code references this struct and, depending on the platform it's running on, the "texture" member can be of any type: SDL_Texture, kgl_Tex, byte[], etc.

How can i create a struct with a flexible member type and allow my code to support multiple platform-specific types? BTW, i'm on ANSI C.

Here's a more "real" example of what i'm looking for:

```
typedef struct
{
    int frames;
    int x;
    int y;
    ? *texture;
} Sprite;

void load_sprite()
{
    Sprite sprite;

    sprite.texture = load_sdl_sprite('test.png'); // This will return a SDL_Texture*
    sprite.texture = load_kgl_sprite('test.png'); // This will return a kgl_tex*
    sprite.texture = load_lib_sprite('test.png'); // This will return a sprite_t*
}
```

Comment: No, it's not a variable length array that i'm looking for: it's assigning variables of different types to the same member. Like generics, in C++.

Comment: You could try `union`

Comment: I have updated my question with a more clear and concise example.

Comment: You need a generic `void *texture`.

Answer (score 3):

If it's only a single value, that's basically "a pointer", I would probably solve it by aliasing that pointer, with a different alias for each platform:

```
#if defined WITH_SDL
 #include SDL-specific headers
 typedef SDL_Surface Texture;
#elif defined WITH_KGL
 #include KGL-specific headers
 typedef kgl_tex Texture;
#elif defined WITH_LIB
 #include LIB-specific headers
 typedef sprite_t Texture;
#else
 #error Undefined platform, no Texture representation.
#endif

typedef struct
{
    int frames;
    int x;
    int y;
    Texture *texture;
} Sprite;
```

This has the (epic) win of keeping the platform's preferred native type in there. It also avoids mentioning other platform's types when not building for them, which can be a big win.

The `typedef` layer might introduce warnings though when assigning e.g. a value of type `SDL_Surface *` into a pointer of type `Texture *`. If that happens, it might be just as well to just `typedef void Texture` and be done with it.

You should put the above in some application-specific header (`sprite.h`) or something, and then `#include` that in all files that need to create a `Texture`. Your example code isn't quite believable; you would never have three calls to different APIs that do the same thing right after each other like that. Typically you'd use preprocessor symbols like above, or have e.g. `sprite-sdl.c`, `sprite-kgl.c` and so on. It's in those files that implement the `Sprite` functionality that you're going to need to `#include` the above.

I added the API-specific includes as placeholders too, that's one way of doing that.

Comment: Now that's elegant. Thanks! :D

Comment: I'm not sure if i get the typedef void Texture, though. When should i do this? Before func calls?

Comment: @vinnylinux The `typedef void Texture;` is *different* solution, if there are problems with using the `typedef` alias (which would require casts). I didn't try it, am not sure. Csats are bad, so if you need to cast you might as well use `void *` to begin with, was my thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Create the variant type as a `void*` in your struct and keep track of what the actual type is based on what your platform is.

Then create access functions on a per platform basis as needed, casting the pointer to what ever type is needed.

```
typedef struct
{
    int frames;
    int x;
    int y;
    void* texture;
} Sprite;


void load_sprite()
{
    Sprite sprite;

    sprite.texture = load_sdl_sprite('test.png'); // This will return a SDL_Texture*
    sprite.texture = load_kgl_sprite('test.png'); // This will return a kgl_tex*
    sprite.texture = load_lib_sprite('test.png'); // This will return a sprite_t*
}
```

Because the texture is of type `void*` you can assign any pointer type you like to it.  It is up to you to keep track of what it is actually pointing to.

Or use lots of `#ifdef` statements to block out the actual type based on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a void pointer field which holds address of actual texture data/struct;
and another int field in the which hold a "type" code, indicating the type of texture.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to keep all possibilities (but it is a wrong idea to keep it) is to make a structure with a type, and an union :

```
enum Texture_type
{
    type_sdl,
    type_kgl,
    type_sprite_t
};

struct Texture
{
   enum Texture_type type;
   union all
   {
       SDL_Surface* Tsdl;          
       kgl_Tex* Tkgl;
       sprite_t* Tspr;
   }
}
```

The structure Texture can hold any of your texture.
Allocating it : you fill the type, and you fill the good pointer into union.
Deleting it : you switch on type to call SDL_FreeSurface or the others